# How to call function in controller from view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My controller is like this :**

```
public function index()
{
    $data_login = $this->session->userdata('login');
    $id = $data_login['customer_id'];

    $this->data['notification'] =  $this->get_data($id);    

    $this->load->view('notification/list_view', $this->data);
}

public function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) 
{
    ...
}
```

**My view (list_view) is like this :**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($notification as $key => $value) 
        {
    ?>

        <tr class="unread" data-messageid="1">
            <td class="view-message "> 
                <?php
                    echo '<a href='.base_url().'notification/notif/'.$value['notification_id'].'>'.$value['notification_message'].'</a><br>';
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message text-right"> <?php echo $this->time_elapsed_string($value['notification_created_date']); ?> </td>
        </tr>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**When executed, there exist error like this :**

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   EX_Loader::time_elapsed_string().....

Seemed unable to call function `time_elapsed_string` in controller.

**Any solution to solve my problem?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you can't use controller's method in view. You have to have helper function.

So, create a helper.php file then, make your function as below:

```
if ( ! function_exists('time_elapsed_string')){
    function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false){
        // do your calculation 
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

Then include your helper.php file into your controller as below:

```
$this->load->helper('helper');
```

Now you will be able to use that "time_elapsed_string" function in your view.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call `$this` function in view, you can use normal function and helper function.

best solution is use function in controller and use `return` value in view.